# Status Bar color not appied to api-21

Tags: android, material-design

Hi all I want to change the status bar color, But Mu status bar color is showing black. I tried to search for this I got couple of question about this on stackOverflow but it does not help me. Still on api-21 it shows me black color.

Following is my `color.xml` inside `values-v21`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="primaryColor">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="primaryColorDark">#FFA000</color>
<color name="accentColor">#F44336</color>
```

my `style.xml` inside `values-v21`

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>


</style>
```

and my `style.xml` is like:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```

As one answer suggest therefore I also tried to add following line before `setContentView(R.layout.main)` as

```
getWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
```

but here i did got error in this line as `getWindows can not resolve symbol`

Comment: well are you using `AppCompat` or the regular theme?

Comment: ok well if you are using `AppCompat` you cannot define stuff with `android:xxx` dont mix normal and compat themes. just use the same style you already have not in the v21 folder

Comment: @tyczj  Actually I have 2 style files. In values-v21/style I am using android:xxx and in normal style.xml I am using <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>

Comment: yes but you are using app compat theme so you cannot use `android:xxx` thats only if you are using `Theme.Material` stuff

Comment: @tyczj  sorry i did not got your point will u please ellaborate. thanks

Comment: the point is dont use `android:xxx` in your style if you are using appcompat!!

Comment: I had remove that but still color is black

Comment: you also dont have a style whose parent is `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in v21. you might as well just delete your v21 style all together, you dont need it

Answer (score 0):

Hey i guess you missed something typo error 'getWindow' to 'getWindow()'
:-
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)

Comment: Ya its typo error, But after correcting it still showing black color

Comment: Are you using it on real device or emulator..??

Comment: If possible try it on real device.

Answer (score 0):

As a sanity check, are you testing on lollipop? even if your using SDK 21 and AppCompat, it will only show on lollipop devices.

Assuming you are testing on lollipop, the next thing I would check is that the theme is being applied to your activity (or set as the default theme) in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi, Yes I am testing it on lolliopo. I know it will only shows on lollipop. And in manifest file I am using  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >